# How to turn Hibernate Envers (ON / OFF) through persistence XML

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

In my application, I'm using Hibernate Envers 4.2.12 for creating audit trail module.It's working fine but at sometimes I need to turn audit trail off so can I configure this at persistence XML ?

Note: After search, I found the below properties to disable Hibernate Envers service and I tried it but it not worked

```
<property name="hibernate.integration.envers.enabled" value="false" />
<property name="hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your property is wrong. Did you try this?

```
<property name="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it now and it's working.Thank you. When I was searching, I found this property is "Legacy setting" at this link: [http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-envers] and also found that the properties I posted are working with Hibernate 4.3 at this link: [https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10056] and I'm using Hibernate 4.2 . Again thank you very much for your answer.